# How do I make Wordpress load my html and css code

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So I've been trying to create a homepage for my WP website that would have its own design not based on the theme. I want it to be a simple html and css page and then Wordpress stuff kicks in when a user clicks a link. I don't need header, footer sidebar tags or anything like that, you could say I just want an html/css homepage separate from the Wordpress.

I've read about custom templates and tried editing theme functions by adding this:

```
function wpse_enqueue_page_template_styles() {
if ( is_page_template( 'customhome.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'page-template', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-home.css' );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_page_template_styles' );
```

but when I create a page with the template it shows me plain html and doesn't load css.

I'm quite new to Wordpress theme editing and don't know php that much but adding your own html/css is said to be quite easy in WP.

How do I integrate my code into WP so it loads only my html with the correct css?

Comment: Does `is_page_template( 'customhome.php' )` return `true` when you want it loaded? Have you tried without it? Can you add the directory-structure perhaps?

Comment: Home.php is used for homepage, if available. Have you considered creating `home.php` with a custom header to load your CSS?

Comment: @Jeppe like I said, the html from the customhome.php loads so I'd assume it returns true, the console doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: @WhereDidMyBrainGo I guess this is where I fail, making it load my css. I will try the same code with home.php but what should I put in the header? Or do you mean the usual code pointing to the css file as in any html?

Comment: The "usual code" in home.php's header. See [Template Files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/)